How to set url id to a specific field cherrypy framework?
urls.py

cherrypy.tree.mount(Hello(),"/",config={})

I want to change the url to something like this..

cherrypy.tree.mount(Hello(),"/{id}",config={})

How can,
import cherrypy 


class Article(object):

    @cherrypy.expose 
    def index(self):
        id = cherrypy.request.params.get("id")
        return f"Id: {id}"

if __name__ == "__main__":

    


    cherrypy.tree.mount(Article(),"/{id}",config={})


    cherrypy.engine.start()
    cherrypy.engine.block()

